# Display the numbers of an array on html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

What I'm trying to do is to make an array of random numbers(no duplicates) and display those numbers on the canvas. What i've done so far is to create the array and display them on the screen but NOT on the canvas. In order to draw each of these numbers on the canvas i presume im gonna need global var pointing on the arrays indexed numbers so i can use the fill methods of the canvas.  this is my code:

```
function fillArrayRandomNumbers(arr, max ){
for (var i = 0 ; i < arr.length ; i++ )
{
   arr[i] = Math.floor(Math.random()*max + 1); 
}
 return arr;
}
function displayArray(arr)
{
  document.write("<br />");
  for (var i = 0 ; i < arr.length ; i++ )
  {
    document.write("Element[" + i +"] = " + arr[i] + "<br />");
  }
  document.write("<br />");
 }
```

Comment: something like this ? http://jsfiddle.net/7qmcynb9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to have a look at the [fillText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Drawing_text#fillText%28%29) method for the canvas. See code below for reference:

```js
function fillArrayRandomNumbers(arr, max) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * max + 1);
  }
  console.log(arr)
  return arr;
}

function displayArray(arr) {
  canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas")
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d")
  context.font = "20px Georgia";
  console.log(arr.length)
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    console.log(arr[i]);
    context.fillText(arr[i], i * 30, 50);//Be smarter here to control where text displays

  }
}

var new_array = Array(10)
new_array = fillArrayRandomNumbers(new_array, 10)
displayArray(new_array)
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="100" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
</canvas>
```